# Open and close divs separately with jQuery and adClass / removeClass

Tags: jquery, html, css, overlay, addclass

I have a page with some hidden fullscreen divs. Now I'm trying to achieve, that I can open these divs SEPARATELY by clicking on the relative button
and close them by clicking the "close"-button inside the div.

At the moment, I can open a div but when I close it, the next one shows up without possibility to close it.

Here is my code:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(".overlay").addClass("overlay-open");         
    $(".closeoverlay").click(function() {   
        $("#overlay1").removeClass("overlay-open");
        $(".overlay").addClass( "overlay-close" );  
    });
```

I made a Fiddle to get it more clear: http://jsfiddle.net/xq2gw50d/

Comment: if you could demonstrate with [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) it will be much easier to help you. right now I don't really understand what you trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you please provide HTML as well?

Comment: What about your HTML?

Answer (score 2):

I Think this should be like below because your `closeoverlay` click inside the `button click` at the moment so that would  create the problem. just make `closeoverlay click` event outside of `button click` as below:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="button" data-rel="overlay1" id="go1">Open Overlay 1</a>  
<a href="#" class="button" data-rel="overlay2" id="go2">Open Overlay 2</a>  
<div class="overlay" id="overlay1">Overlay 1
    <div class="closeoverlay">X</div>
</div>
<div class="overlay" id="overlay2">Overlay 2
    <div class="closeoverlay">X</div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    var overlay = $(this).data('rel')
    $("#" + overlay).addClass("overlay-open");
});
$(".closeoverlay").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('.overlay').removeClass("overlay-open");  
});
```

**EDIT:**

```
$(".button").click(function () {
    var overlay = $(this).data('rel')
    $("#" + overlay).addClass("overlay-open");
    $("#" + overlay).removeAttr("style");

});
$(".closeoverlay").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('.overlay').fadeOut(function () {
        $(this).closest('.overlay').removeClass("overlay-open");
    });
});
```

[JSFILLDE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xq2gw50d/5/)

Comment: @JPC Please check my update answer and working demo.

Comment: @JPC please check my edit part for animation when closing overlay.

Comment: That's better but I know that it IS possible, to use the css animation for closing, too...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
 $("a").click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $("#"+id).removeClass('hidden').addClass("overlay-open");
});         
$(".closeoverlay").click(function() {   
    $(this).parent().removeClass("overlay-open");
    $(this).parent().addClass( "hidden" );  
});
```

```css
.hidden{display:none;}
.overlay {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #915E36;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 z-index: 3;
 float: left;
 display: none;
 background-position: center center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 }

.closeoverlay {
 float: right;
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
 padding: 10px;
 background-image: url(../images/icon_close.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 cursor: pointer;
 opacity: 1;
 
 }

.closeoverlay:hover {
 opacity: 0.8;
 }
 
 .overlay-open {
    display: block;
    animation: openoverlay linear 0.2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation: openoverlay linear 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-animation: openoverlay linear 0.2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-animation: openoverlay linear 0.2s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-animation: openoverlay linear 0.2s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
 
}

@keyframes openoverlay {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(0px,200px)  scaleX(0.50) scaleY(0.50);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(0px,0px)  scaleX(1.00) scaleY(1.00);
    };
}

@-moz-keyframes openoverlay {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translate(0px,200px)  scaleX(0.50) scaleY(0.50);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translate(0px,0px)  scaleX(1.00) scaleY(1.00);
    };
}

@-webkit-keyframes openoverlay {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px,200px)  scaleX(0.50) scaleY(0.50);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px)  scaleX(1.00) scaleY(1.00);
    };
}

@-o-keyframes openoverlay {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translate(0px,200px)  scaleX(0.50) scaleY(0.50);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: translate(0px,0px)  scaleX(1.00) scaleY(1.00);
    };
}

@-ms-keyframes openoverlay {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translate(0px,200px)  scaleX(0.50) scaleY(0.50);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translate(0px,0px)  scaleX(1.00) scaleY(1.00);
    };
}


.overlay-close {
    display: block;
    animation: closeoverlay linear 0.2s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation: closeoverlay linear 0.2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -moz-animation: closeoverlay linear 0.2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -o-animation: closeoverlay linear 0.2s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -ms-animation: closeoverlay linear 0.2s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes closeoverlay {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate(0px,0px)  scaleX(1.00) scaleY(1.00);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate(0px,100px)  scaleX(0.50) scaleY(0.50);
    };
}

@-moz-keyframes closeoverlay {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transform: translate(0px,0px)  scaleX(1.00) scaleY(1.00);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -moz-transform: translate(0px,100px)  scaleX(0.50) scaleY(0.50);
    };
}

@-webkit-keyframes closeoverlay {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px)  scaleX(1.00) scaleY(1.00);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate(0px,100px)  scaleX(0.50) scaleY(0.50);
    };
}

@-o-keyframes closeoverlay {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -o-transform: translate(0px,0px)  scaleX(1.00) scaleY(1.00);
    }

    100% {

        opacity: 0;
        -o-transform: translate(0px,100px)  scaleX(0.50) scaleY(0.50);
    };
}

@-ms-keyframes closeoverlay {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        -ms-transform: translate(0px,0px)  scaleX(1.00) scaleY(1.00);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        -ms-transform: translate(0px,100px)  scaleX(0.50) scaleY(0.50);
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="button" data-id="overlay1">Open Overlay 1</a> 
<a href="#" class="button" data-id="overlay2">Open Overlay 2</a> 

<div class="overlay" id="overlay1"> Overlay 1
<div class="closeoverlay">X</div> 
</div>

<div class="overlay" id="overlay2"> Overlay 2
<div class="closeoverlay">X</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: instead of $(this).addClass("overlay-open");

Comment: Well, I'd like to have the close-animation, too.